# LIstview items bound but not visible WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

ItemsSource of ListView shows loaded item but items are not visible in the screen.

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="...Controls.ControlToolbar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TuningInterfaceModel.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>

    <local:StringFormatToImageSourceConverter x:Key="StringToImage" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" x:Name="tStack">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Key, Converter={StaticResource StringToImage}
 , ConverterParameter=../Images/ControlIcons/{0}.ico}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="10px"  Width="60px" Margin="2,0,0,0"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="/Images/Cursor/grab.cur"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Property="local:MouseExtensions.IsMouseLeftButtonDown" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="/Images/Cursor/Handover.cur" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

Comment: set ItemSource for ListView.

Comment: public void LoadControls()
        {
            tStack.ItemsSource = Global.Controls;
        }

Comment: done it in the codebehind

Comment: issue resolved or still facing the same?

Comment: Still have the same issue

Comment: Any errors in the output-window?

Comment: Make sure that `Key` is a public property in your item class.

Comment: its a public dictionary<> object

Comment: Are you using INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: no not using it.

Comment: Could you show us the code for your items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">` is at fault. It is setting `Template` as a `ControlTemplate` that only contains triggers without any content.

If my crystal balls don't fail me, you may want to remove the control template and use `Style.Triggers` instead.

```xaml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="/Images/Cursor/grab.cur"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <!-- More triggers -->
</Style>
```